# How to grant remote windows service control permissions for a service account

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions

I am setting up a recurring task run by a service account which will need to stop/start services on remote machines at various times. The service account shouldn't require admin rights, just access to the services needed. Using subinacl grants the service specific rights, but doesn't seem to grant all the rights necessary to manage it remotely.

I used subinacl.exe to grant the account stop/start permissions with `subinacl.exe /service \\machine\myservice /GRANT=Domain\SVCAccount=TOP`, and added the account to the remote machine's remote management user group so that it can access it via Invoke-Command.

When I run

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $SVCcredential -ComputerName server -ScriptBlock {Restart-Service service}
```

I get the error **Cannot find any service with service name 'name'**. I looked into this a bit, and found people discussing SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE rights, but I cannot find a way to grant that right to a noninteractive user. I am sure the name of the service is correct, as removing the account credentials from invoke-command and running it as myself works.

I've also tried using net stop/start as the service account, it does not return an error but it also does not restart the service. It just seems to do nothing.

Am I missing something simple with subinacl.exe that would fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft [service-security-and-access-rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-security-and-access-rights):

> The SCM creates a service object's security descriptor when the service is installed by the CreateService function. The default security descriptor of a service object grants the following access.

> **Remote authenticated users: Not granted by default.**
>
> - Windows Server 2003 with SP1: SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL
> - Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP: The access rights for remote authenticated users are the same as for local authenticated users.

When using `Invoke-Command` it is probably like being a "remote authenticated user" and so unless your service account is member of local groups like 'administrators' it is unlikely you're being granted the right to restart a service.

Nevertheless this should probably work using your service account with the task scheduler, because the service account should be considered a "Local authenticated users". And "Local authenticated users" have the READ_CONTROL right by default on services (unless the sercurity descriptor on your service has been changed).

> Local authenticated users (including LocalService and NetworkService)
> READ_CONTROL
> SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS
> SERVICE_INTERROGATE
> SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG
> SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS
> SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL

You need to check that your service account is granted the right:

- "Log on as a batch job" security right (using local policy or group policies).

To test I would recommend you to use `Get-Service` while being either interactively logged on the remote computer or using the task scheduler launching a test PowerShell script.
You can also use `Start-Transcript` to get some output if non interactively connected (with the task scheduler).

If you want to check the Security Descriptor for a service you can use:

```
sc sdshow wuauserv
```

You can then transform the SDDL form in PowerShell:
There is probably alternate code/methods available or even a dedicated library I'm not aware of.

```
$sd = [System.Security.AccessControl.RawSecurityDescriptor]::new("D:(A;;RPWPDT;;;WD)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)")
```

I will not dig into SecurityDescriptor. But it is like security descriptor on files and folder. But the mask (or rights) have other meanings.
Each service has a Security Descriptor that grant access to specific actions.

```
$sd.DiscretionaryAcl | Select-Object AceType, AccessMask, @{l='Identity'; e={[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($_.SecurityIdentifier).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
```

By example the result is as following:

```
AceType AccessMask Identity                
------- ---------- --------                
AccessAllowed        112 Everyone                
AccessAllowed     131469 NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
AccessAllowed     131469 NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE    
AccessAllowed     131581 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM     
AccessAllowed     983551 BUILTIN\Administrators
```

If we dig a bit further to transform the AccessMask into a more readable form:

```
$rights = @{
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF01FF 
    SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x0002 
    SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS = 0x0008 
    SERVICE_INTERROGATE = 0x0080 
    SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE = 0x0040 
    SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x0001 
    SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = 0x0004 
    SERVICE_START = 0x0010 
    SERVICE_STOP = 0x0020 
    SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL= 0x0100 
    DELETE = 0x10000 
    READ_CONTROL = 0x20000 
    WRITE_DAC = 0x40000 
    WRITE_OWNER = 0x80000 
    GENERIC_READ = 0x0001 + 0x0004 + 0x0080 + 0x0008 
        <#
         STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ
        SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS
        SERVICE_INTERROGATE
        SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS
         #>
    GENERIC_WRITE = 0x0002
        <#
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE
        SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG
        #>
    GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x0010 + 0x0020 + 0x0040 + 0x0100
        <#
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE
        SERVICE_START
        SERVICE_STOP
        SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE
        SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL
        #>
}

$sd.DiscretionaryAcl | Select-Object AceType, `
    @{l='Rights'; e={
        foreach($key in $rights.Keys) {
            if (($_.AccessMask -band $rights[$key]) -eq $rights[$key]) {
                $key
            }
        }
     }}, `
     @{l='Identity'; e={[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($_.SecurityIdentifier).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
```

The result is as following:

```
      AceType Rights                                                                                                     Identity                
      ------- ------                                                                                                     --------                
AccessAllowed {SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE, SERVICE_STOP, SERVICE_START}                                                      Everyone                
AccessAllowed {SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS, SERVICE_INTERROGATE, SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS...} NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
AccessAllowed {SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS, SERVICE_INTERROGATE, SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS...} NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE    
AccessAllowed {SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL, SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS, SERVICE_INTERROGATE...}       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM     
AccessAllowed {GENERIC_WRITE, SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL, SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS...}             BUILTIN\Administrators
```

With that knowledge you can check if your service has the default security descriptor. Here the "Everyone" special group is present and should normally apply to "remote authenticated users" as well.
I'm a bit confused if "Everyone" group doesn't apply to a "remote authenticated user".
So for this specific service "wuauserv" (Windows Update Service) any authenticated user should be granted the right to restart it.

Another tip is to use the command `whoami /all` to check to which groups your service account belongs when either:

- using `Invoke-Command`
- running a task

In last resort, you can eventually modify your "service" security descriptor to explicitly grant your service account the right to stop and start the service. I won't go into the details, you have to update the SDDL form of the security descriptor and use `sc sdset` command.

Comment: And so to complete I would say you have to use PLTO in subinacl to grant your service account the "Read Control" right. This may be the only thing missing.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the info! I tried granting PLTO, but get the same error. I ran whoami /all through invoke-command as the service account, and it shows it's a member of the remote management users group as well as the default users group. So seems it is being seen as a builtin member. I guess for now though I'll do this portion of our automation with scheduled tasks